# Flex-basis unless no child exists

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following layout using the flex css, and my left container is set to hav the width 20%. I want it to collapse if .col.left-col is empty (som divs is rendered there .my-left-div)

If i change `.grid--container .left-col` to `.grid--container .my-left-div` the width of the .left-col is no more 20% but more, is that possible to solve without javascript?

```
---------------------------------
|         top                   |
---------------------------------
|       |            |          |
|  left |   middle   |  right   |
|       |            |          |
|       |            |          |
|       |            |          |
|       |            |          |
|       |------------------------
|       |          bottom       |
---------------------------------
```

the html is like this.

```css
    .grid--container {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      justify-content: left;
    }
    .grid--container .left-col {
      flex: 0;
      flex-basis: 20%;
    }
    .grid--container .top {
      margin-top: 28px;
    }
    .grid--container .right-col {
      flex: 1;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    .grid--container .wrapper {
      display: flex;
    }
    .grid--container .wrapper > div {
      flex: 1;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="grid--container">
      <div class="col left-col">
        left
      </div>

      <div class="col right-col">
        <div class="top">
          top
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="middle">
            middle
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            right
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="bottom">
          bottom
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may use ` .grid--container .left-col:empty {flex-basis:0%}`. The requirement for the `:empty` selector is: no space, no comments, nothing!

Comment: grid might be better for this

Comment: @enxaneta thank you, that solves it perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved:**

By using the :empty selector.

```css
    .grid--container {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      justify-content: left;
    }
    .grid--container .left-col {
      flex: 0;
      flex-basis: 20%;
    }
    .grid--container .left-col:empty {
      flex-basis: 0%;
    }
    .grid--container .top {
      margin-top: 28px;
    }
    .grid--container .right-col {
      flex: 1;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    .grid--container .wrapper {
      display: flex;
    }
    .grid--container .wrapper > div {
      flex: 1;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="grid--container">
      <div class="col left-col">
        left
      </div>

      <div class="col right-col">
        <div class="top">
          top
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="middle">
            middle
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            right
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="bottom">
          bottom
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```